# Cucumber to test background color of a webpage

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber

I want set a background color and use cucumber to validate that the correct color is set as background color for the webpage.

I have the below Scenario:

```
Then I follow "Use theme"    
Then the page background should be blue
```

And the step definition as:

> Then /^the page background should be blue$/ do
>   page.evaluate_script("%Q[jQuery('body').css('background-color');]").should
>   == 'rgb(1, 31, 69)' end

But htis is throwing a javascript error 
Can someone please tell me where im going wrong? (PS: Im not very good at jQuery)

Error:

> Then the page background should be blue 
>         syntax error (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `"%Q[ ]"` part. It looks like you are accidentally trying to define a Ruby string in a Ruby string. You either want to wrap the string in "" or %Q[] but not both.

Either of the following would work:

```
# Using %Q[]
puts page.evaluate_script(%Q[jQuery('body').css('background-color');])

# Using ""
puts page.evaluate_script("jQuery('body').css('background-color');")    

# Using $ instead of jQuery
puts page.evaluate_script('$("body").css("background-color")')
```